# Constrained optimization with hessian in scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I want to minimize a function, subject to constraints (the variables are non-negative). I can compute the gradient and Hessian exactly. So I want something like:

```
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(objective, x0, jac=grad, hess=hess, bounds=bds)
```

I need to specify a method for the optimization (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Unfortunately I can't seem to find a method that allows for both user-specified bounds and a Hessian!

This is particularly annoying because methods "TNC" and "Newton-CG" seem essentially the same, however TNC estimates Hessian internally (in C code), while Newton-CG doesn't allow for constraints.

So, how can I do a constrained optimization with user-specified Hessian? Seems like there ought to be an easy option for this in scipy -- am I missing something?

Comment: SciPy's trust-constr claims to do exactly this. Unfortunately it actually doesn't. It just ignores the bounds you give it. Did you find any good solution in the mean time?

Answer (score 1):

I realized a workaround for my problem, which is to transform the constrained optimization into an unconstrained optimization.

In my case, since I have the constraint x > 0, I decided to optimize over log(x) instead of x. This was easy to do for my problem since I am using automatic differentiation.

Still, this seems like a somewhat unsatisfying solution -- I still think scipy should allow some constrained second-order minimization method.

Answer (score 0):

just bumped into exactly this point myself. I think the TNC applies an active set to the line search of the CG, not the direction of the line search. Conversely the Hessian chooses the direction of the line. So, er, could maybe cut the line search out of NCG and drop it into TNC. Problem is when you are at the boundary the Hessian might not take you out of it.

How about using TNC for an extremely sloppy first guess [give it a really large error bound to hit], then use NCG with a small number of iterations, check: if on boundary back to TNC, else continue with NCG. Ugh...

Yes, or use log(x). I'm going to follow your lead.

Comment: any chance you figured this out over the years. There now is trust-constr which claims to do this but actually it ignores your bounds.

Comment: Sorry, no. I settled on L-BFGS-B which worked out pretty well.